# Method doesn't wait for async REST call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working with a lot of async calls in my React app and I would like someone to clarify an issue I ran into.

I came to this issue while I was trying to do two async calls with redux. I've done this a few times and it always worked, however this time, the async calls were neglected - somehow the `Promise` was faster than my redux action.

- I am calling this method via a button.

  ```
  handle = object => {
      if (object) {
          this.edit(object);
      }
  }
  ```
- then edit is called

  ```
  edit = async object => {
      await this.props.createElement(object); // sets editedElement in store via REST call, then dispatches an action
      this.propsdoSmthElse(this.props.editedElement); // do smth with store var
  }
  ```
- After calling `handle()`, `createElement()` is called, it waits till it finishes and then calls `doSmthElse()`, however, `editedElement` is undefined in store.
- Now, if I changed it up like this, it works. `this.props.editedElement` is **NOT** undefined. So, I'm calling only `handle()`. There's no method in between which is not `async`.

`

```
handle = async object => {
    if (object) {
        // sets editedElement in store via REST call, then dispatches an action
        await this.props.createElement(object);
        // do smth with store var
        this.props.doSmthElse(this.props.editedElement);
    }
}
`
```

All methods are in `mapDispatchToProps` and `this.props.editedElement` is brought in by `mapStateToProps`.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ 
    editedElement: state.someReducer.editedElement
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    createElement: object => dispatch(createElement(object)),
    doSmthElse: editedElement => dispatch(doSmthElse(editedElement))
});
```

So, calling both methods right after clicking the button works for me. If I call them from another function, it just fails somehow and my store variable is undefined.
I noticed that the methods are being called in the right order, but the first example doesn't work.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

1)

```
<Button onClick={this.handle}>ClickMe</Button>


handle = object => {
    if (object) {
        this.edit(object);
    }
}

edit = async object => {
    await this.props.createElement(object);
    console.log(this.props.editedElement);
    this.propsdoSmthElse(this.props.editedElement);
}
```

`

2)

```
<Button onClick={this.edit}>ClickMe</Button>


edit = async object => {
    await this.props.createElement(object);
    console.log(this.props.editedElement);
    this.propsdoSmthElse(this.props.editedElement);
}
```

`

- `console.log()` from 1) prints `undefined` but 2) prints the received object. For both variants, my reducer correctly prints the object and I always receive one.

Comment: In the first scenario, where in the code did you verify `this.props.editedElement` is undefined? Note that `handle` will return immediately -- also it doesn't await anything, so if you were checking right  after the call to `handle`, that would be expected. But in `edit()` you should have the value set after `await` is over.

Comment: No, I didn't verify if undefined. I don't understand why the value's undefined in store, since I even print it in my reducer and it is there. If I used the second version of the code, it works. I don't get it.

Comment: It is undefined because you look at it before the async function's promise has resolved. You need to stick with the asynchronous pattern all the way.

Comment: If I `console.log(this.props.editedElement)` after `await this.props.createElement(object);` it's undefined, yes. But in the second scenario, it is not.

Comment: Where exactly *after* you do the `console.log`? Can you edit your question to give the code that does not work in *one* continuous script block, including the `console.log` that outputs `undefined`, so it is reproducible?

Comment: I edited my post! Hope that clears the issue.

Comment: There is no reason why there would be a difference. I hope you can provide a fiddle that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
edit = async object => {
    await this.props.createElement(object); // sets editedElement in store via REST call, then dispatches an action
    await this.propsdoSmthElse(this.props.editedElement); // do smth with store var
}
```

Comment: I tried that too. `this.props.editElement` was still undefined if I called `edit()` from another method. But I why would I have to await the second method too?